# SwiftUI - Value of type '[Color]' has no member 'identified'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(colors.identified(by: \.self)) { color in
                Text(color.description.capitalized)
                    .padding()
                    .background(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the error:

> Value of type '[Color]' has no member 'identified'

What could be the reason? I'm using Xcode 11 beta 5.

Comment: identified is deprecated, use id:\.self instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Xcode 11 Beta 5 and **above**, use:

```
ForEach(colors, id: \.self)
```

For Xcode 11 Beta 4 and **below** use:

```
ForEach(colors.identified(by: \.self))
```